# How to increase memory into a R process?

Tags: r, out-of-memory, memory-limit

I have 12 files (one for each month of the year), each files contains more than **6 million** registers with sales data. I need to collapse each file only to one register with the total sum of columns.

I wrote the following code for january and works,

```
jan18 <- read.delim("C:/Documents/invoices_201801.txt") %>% 
  mutate(dt = ymd(date)) %>% 
  mutate(month=month(dt)) %>%
  group_by(DOCUMENT) %>% 
  summarise(BASE_GRAVADA = mean(BASE_GRAVADA), BASE_TARIFA_0 = mean(BASE_TARIFA_0), BASE_EXCENTA = mean(BASE_EXCENTA), 
            BASE_NO_OBJETO= mean(BASE_NO_OBJETO), MONTO_IVA = mean(MONTO_IVA), VALOR_RETENCION_IVA = mean(VALOR_RETENCION_IVA),
            TOTAL_SIN_IMPUESTOS = mean(TOTAL_SIN_IMPUESTOS), IMPORTE_TOTAL = mean(IMPORTE_TOTAL),mes=mean(mes)) %>%
  group_by(month) %>% 
   summarise(BASE_GRAVADA = sum(BASE_GRAVADA), BASE_TARIFA_0 = sum(BASE_TARIFA_0), BASE_EXCENTA = sum(BASE_EXCENTA), 
             BASE_NO_OBJETO= sum(BASE_NO_OBJETO), MONTO_IVA = sum(MONTO_IVA), VALOR_RETENCION_IVA = sum(VALOR_RETENCION_IVA),
             TOTAL_SIN_IMPUESTOS = sum(TOTAL_SIN_IMPUESTOS), IMPORTE_TOTAL = sum(IMPORTE_TOTAL))
```

but when I want to run the same code for the following months there is a message error:

```
 Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  could not allocate memory (2048 Mb) in C function 'R_AllocStringBuffer'
```

Can give me some help with tips to avoid this **memory** problem? I tried with gc() and set up memory limit but I obtain the same error message.

Comment: While I understand the appeal of `dplyr` and use it for many projects, whenever I start using larger data (such as this), I gravitate towards `data.table` and its memory-efficient operations. R in general (and `dplyr` is no exception to this) operates by *copy-on-write*, which means that often when you make a change to something (like a frame-column), it makes a complete copy of the entire thing before assigning the new value into place. `data.table`, in contrast, operates primarily by side-effect. `data.table`'s syntax can be hard, you might consider the `dtplyr` package.

Comment: (Other than that ... the way to give more memory to R is to give more memory to the computer ... $$$)

Comment: Are you using 64-bit R? Also, if your $$$ is limited, when you've finished one month, restart R and do the next month. And consider `fread` for importing the data files.